# Having problems opening a custom enterprise app from with another custom app

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I have a couple of custom apps (masterapp and app2), both belonging to the same custom URL scheme. When I click a button on the masterapp, I want it to open app2.

I've noticed a weird pattern where by the master app only opens app2 if app2 was installed before the master app.

If I install the masterapp, then install app2 then click the button to open app2 it just doesn't do anything.

Can anyone explain this behaviour and what is going on? I've played around with URL schemes for days now but can't get this to work properly.

Comment: Are you saying both iOS apps register the same custom URL scheme? You can't do that. Every app must have a unique scheme.

Comment: OK I think you might have point me in the right direction. In both apps under URL types I have the same thing setup as I thought they had to both belong to the same scheme by doing this? Do I only need to setup the URL type in the master app? Nothing in app2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't do this.**

The URI scheme need to be unique to each app. There have actually been a few instances where third-party apps attempt to hijack the private URI schemes of popular apps, and this is part of the reason Apple introduced Universal Links in iOS 9.

If you think it through logically, the behavior you are experiencing makes perfect sense: if two apps with the same URI scheme are installed, then the app you installed first is the one that will respond when that URI scheme is triggered.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I think your answer has helped point me in the right direction. Same as rmaddy. Do I only need to setup the URL type / LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in the master app and nothing in app2?

Comment: The destination app needs to have a scheme so you can target it. In this case, that would be app2. Whether or not the origin app (master app, here) has a scheme or not is irrelevant for this particular situation.

Comment: I got it working now. I removed the URL Types from my Master App, left the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in the Plist of the master app and then setup a URL Type in app2. Thanks for the guidance!